# ExtJS 4.1 TreeStore doesn't load with association

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a TreeStore, which works fine, but every node has some nested data, so I made a new model for it and used the `hasMany` association. But now the store loads nothing anymore. When I look into the records in the `load` event, they're empty, but the browser tells me the Ajax request delivered everything like before.

This is what the node data looks like, when it comes from the server:

```
{
  "path": "KEY_518693",
  "name": "KEY_518693",
  "data": [
    {
      "branch": "KEY_518693",
      "primnav": "ETC",
      "X": 29261,
      "Y": 96492
    },
    ...
  ],
  "children": [ ... ],
  ...
}
```

These are my model definitions:

```
TreeNode:
{
  extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
  requires: [
    'DataRecord',
    'Ext.data.association.HasMany'
  ],
  fields  : [
    { name: 'id'  , type: 'string', mapping: 'path' },
    { name: 'text', type: 'string', mapping: 'name' },
    ...
  ],
  hasMany : {
    model: 'DataRecord',
    name : 'data'
  }
```

```
DataRecord:
{
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    { name: 'branch' , type: 'string'},
    { name: 'primnav', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'X'      , type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Y'      , type: 'int' }
  ]
}
```

When I remove the association, the tree loads without problems. When I add `data` to the fields it gets parsed into the tree, but as "raw" object and not as model instance.

Comment: As first step to solve this issue, please note that `DataRecord` has no field called `treenode_id` - so your hasMany association isn't complete. See [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany) for more info.

Comment: Oh yes, I saw it. after I made `primaryKey: 'branch'` it worked. Also I had an error with the `name`, which should not be `data`

Comment: yes, after setting the name, the records got loaded again and after setting the primaryKey they were filled with the parsed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that DataRecord has no field called treenode_id - so your hasMany association isn't complete. See [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

My approach had 2 problems.

1. The name of the association should not be 'data' or the records wont get loaded at all.
2. The primaryKey of the association has to be set right, in my case `'branch'` was right